# Primefaces wizard encodeStep NPE exception thrown

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have written a webdriver test for my page, which tests a primefaces wizard component and behavior. At one point, I get this error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.primefaces.component.wizard.WizardRenderer.encodeStep(WizardRenderer.java:77)
at org.primefaces.component.wizard.WizardRenderer.encodeEnd(WizardRenderer.java:59)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:517)
at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1612)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:362)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:378)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:298)
at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:183)
at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:183)
at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:183)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:982)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:411)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:124)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:286)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.meinanliegen.handlers.filters.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:42)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.omnifaces.filter.FacesExceptionFilter.doFilter(FacesExceptionFilter.java:56)
at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:75)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.omnifaces.filter.GzipResponseFilter.doFilter(GzipResponseFilter.java:148)
at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:75)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.omnifaces.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:115)
at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:75)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1812)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

My primefaces wizard looks like :

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<p:growl id="growl" autoUpdate="true" life="6000" showDetail="true" />

<h:form prependId="false" style="height : 100%" id="registrationFormWizardId">
    <f:view beforePhase="#{userRegistrationWizard.afterPhase}">
    </f:view>
    <p:panel id="registrationFormWizardPanelGrid">
        <p:panelGrid>
            <p:row>
                <p:column>
                    <p:wizard widgetVar="wiz" flowListener="#{userRegistrationWizard.onFlowProcess}"
                        step="#{userRegistrationWizard.step}" backLabel="Zurück" nextLabel="Weiter">

                        <p:tab id="idOne" title="TITLE1">
                            <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/templates/steps/registration_step1.xhtml"></ui:include>
                        </p:tab>

                        <p:tab id="idTwo" title="TITLE2">
                            <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/templates/steps/registration_step2.xhtml"></ui:include>
                        </p:tab>

                        <p:tab id="idThree" title="TITLE3">
                            <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/templates/steps/registration_step3.xhtml"></ui:include>
                        </p:tab>
                    </p:wizard>
                </p:column>
            </p:row>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

Does someone knows why this exception is being thrown?

UPDATE :

I use Primefaces 3.5 and MyFaces 2.1.17

Comment: Which version of Primefaces are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Java code of `WizardRenderer` id of tab that should be rendered is not found in wizard. This is probably consequence if your test somehow went back on first page, or next on last page.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I think the clicks are too fast, and the button back on first page and next on last page didn't dissapear when test clicked on it. So is there any thing I can do with this or only speed down the tests ?

Comment: Well, I must admit that I'm not very familiar with Webdriver, but definitely test should wait to page to be completely load before go on. I don't know is that possible and easy, but that is more reliable test.